# How to convert coverage to shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, shapefile

I'm using ArcMap 10.1 I recently downloading some files that are in .adf format.

I need to convert them to .shp.

I just simply need step by step instructions of how to convert the data.

Comment: see this post (possible duplicate?). http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102984/dem-file-in-adf-format-while-tiff-is-needed
It is likely GRID (not a coverage).

Comment: Without knowing what was downloaded, it would be difficult to say it was GRID - adf files are used in vector coverages. We have a number of questions on the topic. Two that immediately stand out are http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19047/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98381/ There's also more information in the [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001400000001000000), including a [tutorial exercise](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n0000000n000000). Please **edit** to include what you downloaded and from where.

Answer (score 1):

you can use quick import tool in data interoperabilty toolbox to covert your data to arcgis geodatabase then expot those feature class to shape file.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on ESRI document you can convert by [Feature Class To Feature Class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) tool:

"Converts a shapefile, coverage feature class, or geodatabase feature class to a shapefile or geodatabase feature class"

example:
If you want convert polygon in coverage to shapefile polygon
[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in ArcCatalog. Put all the coverage files in one folder, select all the ones you want to change into shapefiles, right click, export --> shapefile (multiple), then select the output folder and OK. It takes a while but it's so easy!